Не могу прошить ESP32, зависает на 99%
Arduino 1.9.2, ESP32-WROOM обычная.
Купил, делаю обычную прошивку (blink LED). Компилируется, заливается, на 99% останавливается и выдает ошибку терминала timeout. Как быть? На других устройствах всё работает, прошивается. Подскажите, в чём дело?

тут может быть несколько вариантов, пожалуйста приложите фотографию ошибки, но вот несколько советов, которые могут помочь:

Проверьте провод, с помощью которого заливаете прошивку, возможно он плохо подсоединен, поэтому на последнем этапе происходит ошибка
Возможно, у вас в коде где-то допущена ошибка, и поэтому код не может быть скомпилирован

Если будут какие-то вопросы пиши мне в канал: https://t.me/s/my_travel_blogg

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам стали доступны комментарии к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос

Дорогие администраторы просьба не удалять этот вопрос в течении 3 дней, это задание для олимпиады. По завершению соревнований, мы сами удалим вопрос и ответ
